# a MySQL query error in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I've got an MySQL syntax error when I run the following code:

```python
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**connection)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

select_categories = ("select `id`, `name`, `url` from categories where `id_parent`=%s")
cursor.execute( select_categories, (4) )
```

Error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

How to fix it?

Comment: shouldnt it be
`"select id, name, url from categories where", id_parent=%s`

Comment: @Maddy: No. Everything work fine if I set `select_categories = ("select 'id', 'name', 'url' from categories where 'id_parent'=4")
`

Comment: Your param should be sequence. A tuple of one element is `(4,)` but you have `(4)` which is a scalar.

Comment: @Parfait: it works. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that python interprets `(4)` as 4 and the parameter needs to be an iterable. Try to update to this:

```
cursor.execute( select_categories, (4, ) )
```

The comma after the 4 will force python to interpret this as a tuple.